# Price of dividend paying stock

Tags: finance

Consider a dividend paying stock $S$ and suppose that its value just before a dividend payment of $D >0$ at time $t$ is denoted by $S(t−)$. The price after the payment should be $S(t)=S(t-)-D$?

How can I justify that. Is there an arbitrage argument?

Comment: I am confused by the question.  Suppose that you go into a store to buy corn flakes, priced at $P$ with a $\$0.50$ off coupon.  Then the effective price is $(P - 0.50)$ and the price, without the coupon is $P$.  Doesn't this situation analogize to the dividend representing the coupon?

Comment: Yes but I was looking for a rigorous proof, although the situation might be trivial?

Answer (score 0):

If a stock price is the discounted value of future income, then immediately before the dividend, the future income is the amount $S(t-)$, and immediately after the dividend, the future income is the amount $S(t) = S(t-)-D$. It's lessened by $D$ because that's no longer part of the stream of future income. There's nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Why should the stock price be the discounted value of future income?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but it's a common [valuation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_using_discounted_cash_flows).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, because of tax considerations.  Depending on the jurisdiction, capital gains may be taxed at a different rate than dividends.  Depending on these rates, selling a stock before the dividend at $S(t-)$ may be a better or a worse deal than
getting the dividend $D$ and selling at $S(t-)-D$.  If enough investors prefer one to the other, it will affect the stock prices.